# How to run a file from the Windows Run prompt without including the file extension

Tags: windows

If I have a PowerShell script named `myscript.ps1` and it sits in the PATH, I'd like to be able to press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>, type "myscript", and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.  Currently it requires me to type `myscript.ps1`, and it runs fine.

I've found a few answers that suggested `ftype`, `assoc`, and the `PATHEXT` environment variable, but that only affects scripts run from command prompt or PowerShell, not from explore.exe's Run prompt.

I assume there's some registry setting, but I don't know what to search for, as `fileext` has hundreds of entries.  I also searched for `.bat` since batch files work automatically, but I haven't found anything obvious.

I thought I'd found it under under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap` by adding a .ps1 value and setting it to `program` as .bat, .cmd, .com, and .exe all are set that way, but no dice (even after restarting my computer).

I also noticed that .bat, .cmd, .exe, .lnk, and .msi each had an `HKCR\<app-handler-id>\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\ShimLayer Property Page` set to `{513D916F-2A8E-4F51-AEAB-0CBC76FB1AF8}`, but adding that to `HKCR\Microsoft.Powershell.1` didn't worth either.

Comment: You could write a wrapper script, that would list all your personal scripts and let you pick one to run?

Comment: I considered that, and I might do it, but I still want my question answered.  I'm curious how Windows works.

Comment: I guess you need the full name to run things. If you were in a terminal, you could try pressing TAB to auto-complete many things (programs, files, directories...)

Comment: Certain file extensions aren't required though: .bat, .exe, .cmd, etc.  I assume those aren't hard-coded into the OS, so there should be a way to change them and add .ps1.

Comment: Interesting. The Run prompt doesn't seem to respect the `Pathext` environment variable. It doesn't answer the underlying curiosity, but perhaps a DOSKEY macro (aka "Alias") would accomplish your goal. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: make a .bat that runs your powershell. That's what I use, not for the reasons you have listed but because my powershells are located on different server, but I feel like it's a valid work around.

Comment: @EricW. Yeah, I just don't like workarounds in general.  Plus, it requires a batch file for every script unless you want to use the ps1 script as an argument to the batch script; in that case it ends up saving you a total of 2 characters assuming the batch's file name is only 1.  It turns out .lnk (shortcut files) also do not require an extension, so I think I'm going to go that route for my one script.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found for me was here to use the following in a .bat:

```
start wt your-command
exit
```

I'm using Windows Terminal since I like the handling far more than the regular powershell, but this also works with powershell instead of wt.
The exit command is used to close the window in case I'm running it from an open cmd shell.